# Implement Haskell-like primes iterator in Rust

Tags: haskell, rust, iterator, primes

I am trying to implement a Rust iterator similar to the following Haskell code:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = nextPrime [2..]
    where 
        nextPrime (x:xs) = x : nextPrime (filter (notDivBy x) xs)
        notDivBy a x = a `mod` x /= 0
```

My attempt so far ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2688faa1bd581aea1c3a576bf6e26b7c)):

```
// as pointed out in a comment this can simply return Primes and not use Box::new
fn primes() -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>> {
    Box::new(Primes::new())
}

struct Primes {
    nums: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>,
}

impl Primes {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Primes { nums : Box::new(2..) }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Primes {
    type Item = usize;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        
        let prime = self.nums.next().unwrap();
        self.nums = Box::new(self.nums.filter(move |&n|!divides(prime, n)));
        //use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
        //*self.nums.borrow_mut() = self.nums.filter(move |&n|!divides(prime, n));
        Some(prime)
    }
}


pub fn divides(d: usize, n: usize) -> bool {
    n % d == 0
}
```

Unfortunately this runs into:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.nums` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:22:30
   |
22 |         self.nums = Box::new(self.nums.filter(move |&n| !divides(prime, n)));
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.nums` has type `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

Or if you uncomment the alternative borrow_mut code:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'static)>: BorrowMut<Filter<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:24:52: 24:79]>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:24:20
   |
24 |         *self.nums.borrow_mut() = self.nums.filter(move |&n|!divides(prime, n));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorrowMut<Filter<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:24:52: 24:79]>>` is not implemented for `Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'static)>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Box<T, A> as BorrowMut<T>>
```

Frankly I am not even sure which of these two is closer to working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace a value behind a mutable reference by moving and mapping the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67461269/replace-a-value-behind-a-mutable-reference-by-moving-and-mapping-the-original)

Comment: Your usage of Boxing is odd here. Why does `primes()` not just return a `Primes`? Why store a (boxed!) iterator to a thing that counts instead of just a counter directly? I think if you aimed to reduce dynamic allocations it would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @GManNickG, originally i did not have this boxing, but building up the filter chain makes the compiler complain about not being able to determine the size of the iterator, which prompted me to introduce the boxing. IIRC. Maybe I overshot a little in my use of Box?

Comment: @GManNickG, I've added a comment in the code about this now. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can cache the discovered primes:

```rust
fn primes() -> Primes {
    Primes::new()
}

struct Primes {
    nums: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>,
    cache: Vec<usize>,
}

impl Primes {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Primes {
            nums: Box::new(2..),
            cache: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Primes {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        loop {
            let num = self.nums.next().unwrap();
            if self
                .cache
                .iter()
                .take_while(|&&n| n*n <= num)
                .all(|&p| !divides(p, num))
            {
                // we found a prime!
                self.cache.push(num);
                return Some(num);
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn divides(d: usize, n: usize) -> bool {
    n % d == 0
}

fn main() {
    println!("Primes: {:?}", primes().take(10).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd2c9a3be1a744e1a5857daed18c4e39)

Comment: Interesting! With the caching you are even closer to emulating the Haskell semantics.

Comment: @hkBst Actually, I believe this uses a more efficient technique than the original Haskell code, since that will eventually build a large chain of filters `filter p1 (filter p2 (...` instead of keeping a cache around and only apply a single filter. You could modify your Haskell to use a `Set` for the cache and replace the filters with some `unfoldr`, I think.

Comment: @chi, the Haskell code builds up a list of primes, but you are correct that it could perhaps filter more efficiently.

Comment: The loop now looks like a filter btw. But if I try to write it as such I get back to my original problems.

Comment: @hkBst good edit, thanks!

Comment: you can add [`.take(sqrt(num)).all....`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=030b6d2f608053ca9fcca2d13145a0c9), for a _very_ big speedup (using `num::integer::sqrt`). it should really be `takeWhile(|&p| !(p*p > num) )`, but it said "error[E0599]: no method named `takeWhile` found" when I tried it.

Comment: @WillNess, indeed, I didnt use that in the first implementation for lazyness (mine, not in the code :P). But since you bubbled it up I updated it. Thanks!

Comment: it should be `take_while(|&&n| !(n*n > num))`, though. otherwise, the primes' squares are getting through.

Comment: @WillNess `n*n < num` `==` `!(n*n > num)`?

Comment: if course not. =< would be. turns out in Rust that's <=. :)

Comment: That is it. Thanks!

Comment: @WillNess, `.take_while(|&n| n*n <= num)` with 1 `&` seems to work. Any reason for having 2?

Comment: @hkBst it's not me that written that. and I don't know Rust at all. :)

Comment: @hkBst, it is to dereference,  it would work for `&n` and `n` but not `&&n`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really expert in Rust, but one (ugly) option is to replace `self.nums` with a dummy iterator so to be able to move the previous value.

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
    let prime = self.nums.next().unwrap();
    // Ugly replacement with a dummy iterator value
    let rest = std::mem::replace(&mut self.nums, Box::new(0..));
    self.nums = Box::new(rest.filter(move |&n|!divides(prime, n)));
    Some(prime)
}
```

This could be cleaner if we used an `Option` wrapper so that we can use `None` as the dummy value.

Comment: It works, but I do not understand why. :D

Comment: The problem with this iiuc is that you are reboxing en each next call. So by the 10th prime you will already have a box(box(box(box...))) wrapping indirections.

Comment: @Netwave Indeed, it's not efficient. But it's the "dumb" translation of what happens in the original Haskell code, where we get a chain of filters, each one pointing to the other. Running that Haskell code, we do get a larger and larger chain of indirections. The efficient alternative is to cache the primes, as you do -- that applies to both languages.

Comment: @hkBst Assuming that we want to match the original Haskell closely, your issue is that you are trying to do (roughly) `x = f(x)` where `f` consumes (moves) its input `f(x:T)->T`. This is not an issue when we _own_ `x`, but becomes one when we only have a mut reference `y`, since we can't move from it -- we do not own the data. At best, we can `replace` the data with a dummy value, doing `let x = replace(y, dummy)`. After that, we do own `x`, so we can conclude with `*y = f(x)`, overwriting the dummy value.

Comment: [postponing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+postponing) the creation of each filter until the square of its prime is just as efficient as using one unified test which goes through the cached primes (presumably up to the sqrt only).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out (with the help of the other answers) how to fix **cannot move out of `self.nums` which is behind a mutable reference**. The trick is to use `&mut self.nums` (and get rid of the Box).

```
fn primes() -> Primes {
    Primes::new()
}

pub struct Primes {
    nums: std::ops::RangeFrom<usize>,
    cache: Vec<usize>,
}

impl Primes {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Primes {
            nums: 2..,
            cache: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Primes {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        let next_prime = (&mut self.nums)
            .filter(|&n| {
                self.cache
                    .iter()
                    .take_while(|&p| p * p <= n)
                    .all(|&p| !divides(p, n))
            })
            .next()
            .unwrap();
        self.cache.push(next_prime);
        return Some(next_prime);
    }
}

pub fn divides(d: usize, n: usize) -> bool {
    n % d == 0
}

fn main() {
    println!("Primes: {:?}", primes().take(10).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd2c9a3be1a744e1a5857daed18c4e39)